# Magento 2: can't override DirectoryDataProcessor.php with module

Tags: magento2

I am writing a module that overrides DirectoryDataProcessor.php to eliminate blank options in the select drop-down menu for countries in the shipping address.
The module is correctly detected but nothing happens.
If I change the core file with my class DirectoryDataProcessor modified, works.
With module doesn't work.
Thank you for your help.

Here my files:

/app/code/Luca/CountryEmptyDropdown/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor" type="Luca\CountryEmptyDropdown\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor" sortOrder='999'/>
</config>
```

/app/code/Luca/CountryEmptyDropdown/Block/Checkout/DirectoryDataProcessor.php

```
<?php

namespace Luca\CountryEmptyDropdown\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class DirectoryDataProcessor extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $countryOptions;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $regionOptions;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $regionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $countryCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var DirectoryHelper
     */
    private $directoryHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollection
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollection
     * @param StoreResolverInterface $storeResolver @deprecated
     * @param DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollection,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollection,
        StoreResolverInterface $storeResolver,
        DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollection;
        $this->regionCollectionFactory = $regionCollection;
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Process js Layout of block
     *
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
                'country_id' => $this->getCountryOptions(),
                'region_id' => $this->getRegionOptions(),
            ];
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get country options list.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getCountryOptions()
    {
        if (!isset($this->countryOptions)) {
            $this->countryOptions = $this->countryCollectionFactory->create()->loadByStore(
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->toOptionArray();
            $this->countryOptions = $this->orderCountryOptions($this->countryOptions);
        }

        return $this->countryOptions;
    }

    /**
     * Get region options list.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getRegionOptions()
    {
        if (!isset($this->regionOptions)) {
            $this->regionOptions = $this->regionCollectionFactory->create()->addAllowedCountriesFilter(
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->toOptionArray();
        }

        return $this->regionOptions;
    }

    /**
     * Sort country options by top country codes.
     *
     * @param array $countryOptions
     * @return array
     */
    private function orderCountryOptions(array $countryOptions)
    {
        $topCountryCodes = $this->directoryHelper->getTopCountryCodes();
        if (empty($topCountryCodes)) {
            return $countryOptions;
        }

        $headOptions = [];
        $tailOptions = [[
            'value' => 'delimiter',
            'label' => '──────────',
            'disabled' => true,
        ]];

        $countryListIndex = 0;
        foreach ($countryOptions as $countryOption) {
            if (empty($countryOption['value']) || in_array($countryOption['value'], $topCountryCodes)) {
                if($countryOption['value'] != '') {
                    $countryListIndex = $countryListIndex + 1;
                    if ($countryListIndex == 1) {
                        $tailOptions = [[]];
                    }
                    array_push($headOptions, $countryOption);
                }
            } else {
                if($countryOption['value'] != '') {
                    $countryListIndex = $countryListIndex + 1;
                    if ($countryListIndex == 1) {
                        $tailOptions = [[]];
                    }
                    array_push($tailOptions, $countryOption);
                }
            }
        }


        return array_merge($headOptions, $tailOptions);
    }
}
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Luca_CountryEmptyDropdown" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

move di.xml file to frontend folder

**module.xml**

```
<module name="Luca_CountryEmptyDropdown" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
```

**/app/code/Luca/CountryEmptyDropdown/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor" type="Luca\CountryEmptyDropdown\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor"/>

</config>
```

**/app/code/Luca/CountryEmptyDropdown/Block/Checkout/DirectoryDataProcessor.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Luca\CountryEmptyDropdown\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;


/**
 * Directory data processor.
 *
 * This class adds various country and region dictionaries to checkout page.
 * This data can be used by other UI components during checkout flow.
 */
class DirectoryDataProcessor implements \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $countryOptions;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $regionOptions;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $regionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $countryCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var DirectoryHelper
     */
    private $directoryHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollection
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollection
     * @param StoreResolverInterface $storeResolver @deprecated
     * @param DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollection,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollection,
        StoreResolverInterface $storeResolver,
        DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollection;
        $this->regionCollectionFactory = $regionCollection;
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Process js Layout of block
     *
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
                'country_id' => $this->getCountryOptions(),
                'region_id' => $this->getRegionOptions(),
            ];
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get country options list.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getCountryOptions()
    {
        if (!isset($this->countryOptions)) {
            $this->countryOptions = $this->countryCollectionFactory->create()->loadByStore(
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->toOptionArray();
            $this->countryOptions = $this->orderCountryOptions($this->countryOptions);
        }

        return $this->countryOptions;
    }

    /**
     * Get region options list.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getRegionOptions()
    {
        if (!isset($this->regionOptions)) {
            $this->regionOptions = $this->regionCollectionFactory->create()->addAllowedCountriesFilter(
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->toOptionArray();
        }

        return $this->regionOptions;
    }

    /**
     * Sort country options by top country codes.
     *
     * @param array $countryOptions
     * @return array
     */
    private function orderCountryOptions(array $countryOptions)
    {
        $topCountryCodes = $this->directoryHelper->getTopCountryCodes();
        if (empty($topCountryCodes)) {
            return $countryOptions;
        }

        $headOptions = [];
        $tailOptions = [[
            'value' => 'delimiter',
            'label' => '──────────',
            'disabled' => true,
        ]];
        foreach ($countryOptions as $countryOption) {
            if (empty($countryOption['value']) || in_array($countryOption['value'], $topCountryCodes)) {
                $headOptions[] = $countryOption;
            } else {
                $tailOptions[] = $countryOption;
            }
        }
        return array_merge($headOptions, $tailOptions);
    }
}
```

Then try below command

```
sudo rm -rf var/* generated/* pub/static/frontend/*
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

I have checked file is an override.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107182/discussion-on-answer-by-devidas-cant-override-directorydataprocessor-php-with-m).

Answer (score 0):

@goplastic

Where you able to solve the issue of the eliminate blank options in the select drop-down menu for countries in the shipping address?

Whenever I try I get a false option instead of the blank option on the frontend dropwdown. Whereas in my array I have sliced/unset the first index of the countryOptions which was holding the blank value.

Please let me know how you solved this issue.
Thanks (:

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/204299)